# Spring aop is not getting triggerd for external jar method in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am trying to have point cut for a method in jar and it is not getting triggered properly

I have my rest endpoint code as below :

```
package com.example.log.javatpoint;


import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Test{

    @Autowired
    Operation op;

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String custom() {
        op.msg();  
        op.display(); 

        LOG.info("Hello World");
        LOG.info("Hello {0}", "World 2");

        return "custom";
    }
}
```

Operation class :

```
@Component
public  class Operation{
    public void msg(){System.out.println("msg() is invoked");}
    public void display(){System.out.println("display() is invoked");}
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TrackOperation
{
    @Pointcut("execution(* Operation.*(..))")
    public void abcPointcut(){}

    @Around("abcPointcut()")
    public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Additional Concern Before calling actual method");
        Object obj=pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("Additional Concern After calling actual method");
        return obj;
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.info(..))")
    public void abcPointcutLog(){}

    @Around("abcPointcutLog()")
    public Object myAdviceLog(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable 
    {
        System.out.println("Additional Concern Before calling actual method");
        Object obj=pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println("Additional Concern After calling actual method");
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Note : Point cut is working for Operation class where as point cut is not working for `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager` tried also providing `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` in point cut.

I expect the output as :

```
Additional Concern Before calling actual method
2019-09-24 12:28:58.540  INFO 10076 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.log.javatpoint.Test          : Hello World
Additional Concern After calling actual method
Additional Concern Before calling actual method
2019-09-24 12:28:58.540  INFO 10076 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.log.javatpoint.Test          : Hello {0}
Additional Concern After calling actual method
```

but the actual output is :

```
2019-09-24 12:28:58.540  INFO 10076 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.log.javatpoint.Test          : Hello World
2019-09-24 12:28:58.540  INFO 10076 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.log.javatpoint.Test          : Hello {0}
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is a "classic" and has been asked so many times here already...

Please read the Spring AOP manual before using a tool you don't know. It will tell you that [Spring AOP can only be applied to Spring components/beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn), not to non-Spring POJOs. For that you need full AspectJ which you can use within Spring or completely without Spring.

Log4J classes are not Spring components, so the above applies to your situation. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) you find information about how to use AspectJ load-time weaving (LTW) instead of Spring AOP for your purpose.

Comment: Will you be able to provide the code on what need to be changed here to achieve my output.

Comment: It is not code, it is configuration. Did you follow my link about AspectJ LTW?

Comment: I tried providing ```@EnableLoadTimeWeaving``` but was not successful. if you could provide me a working code will be more helpful. Tried everything in that website.

Comment: You need `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` when starting your JVM. `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` only works in combination with some rather tricky container configuration, the Java agent is the safest bet. You also need _aop.xml_ in the right place, but that is all written in the manual. I repeat: This is not about changing code, it is about changing configuration. You are not sharing your configuration or JVM command line here, so how can I tell you what exactly to change? You need to do a little bit of work on your own, too.

Comment: If you share a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. Maven POM on GitHub, I can take a look. But try yourself first and don't use me as a shortcut to not fully reading the documentation.