# Aspect not getting called for external library in spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using Spring boot 2, need to print logs on execution of `org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource()` inside library.

I have created the class and added the dependencies in build.gradle

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class LoggingCollabCustomAspect {

    public static final String TO_STRING_RESULT = "changed";

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(*))")
    public void loadExternalResource()
    {
    }

    @Around("loadExternalResource()")
    public Object showLogs(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        Object ignoredToStringResult = joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("File changed: " + ignoredToStringResult);
        return TO_STRING_RESULT;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '5.1.9.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.4'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.4'
```

I expect the aspect message to be printed but its not working

Comment: If it is not a Spring bean, it will not have pointcut, because Spring creates a runtime-proxy around aspected beans.

Comment: I think aspectjweaver could make it happen without bean

Comment: In that case, you have to use load-time weaving. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384525/8258222

Comment: alright, I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Does anyone ever read the Spring AOP documentation or use the search function on SO before trying to use it as a new technology? This question comes up almost every day here, e.g. I [answered it yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58080416/1082681). BTW, what is the purpose of the `@Configuration` annotation on the aspect? An aspect is not a configuration class, you should put your configuration into a separate class.